# SQL multiplying based on previous calculated row record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created the below query and am trying to have another column that has an initial value of 1000 in the last row and then multiplies original 1000 by the  mdp.DataPointValue and then after the initial 1000 uses the newly calculated value going forward.

For example, on 5/25/10 I would like the starting value to be 1000. On 5/26/10 I would like it to be mdp.DataPointValue * Previous Value (1000 for the first one) and so on. Any help would be much appreciated

```
SELECT        AsOfDate, 
              mdp.DataPointValue
FROM           DataPointPITs AS mdp
WHERE        mdp.DataPointId = '2710' AND AsOfDate > '2010-05-25'
ORDER BY     AsOfDate DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [`LAG()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql)

```
SELECT        AsOfDate, 
              mdp.DataPointValue,
              mdp.DataPointValue * LAG(mdf.DataPointValue, 1, 1000) OVER (ORDER BY AsOfDate DESC) 
FROM           DataPointPITs AS mdp
WHERE        mdp.DataPointId = '2710' AND AsOfDate > '2010-05-25'
ORDER BY     AsOfDate DESC
```

Welcome to the wonderful wacky world of windowing functions.

Comment: I need it to end up looking like where the no column name is = to previous column * DPValue but it needs to start with 5/25/10 as 1000 *AsOfDate     DataPointValue (No column name) 
*6/1/2010     0.81                      1059.144652 
*5/28/2010     0.934                   1307.58599 
*5/27/2010     1.327                   1399.985 
*5/26/2010     1.055                   1055 
*5/25/2010     0.951                   1000

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are always positive (never negative or zero) and have no gaps, you can do a cumulative product using `SUM()` and arithmetic:

```
SELECT AsOfDate, mdp.DataPointValue,
       1000 * exp(sum(log(mdp.DataPointValue)) over (order by AsOfDate))
FROM  DataPointPITs mdp
WHERE mdp.DataPointId = '2710' AND AsOfDate > '2010-05-25'
ORDER BY AsOfDate DESC;
```

Comment: I need it to end up looking like where the no column name is = to previous column * DPValue but it needs to start with 5/25/10 as 1000 *AsOfDate     DataPointValue (No column name) 
*6/1/2010     0.81                      1059.144652 
*5/28/2010     0.934                   1307.58599 
*5/27/2010     1.327                   1399.985 
*5/26/2010     1.055                   1055 
*5/25/2010     0.951                   1000

Comment: @djk11 . . . Isn't that what this does?

Comment: @djk11 . . . I fixed the answer.  SQL Server calls the function `log()`.

Comment: Msg 3623, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
An invalid floating point operation occurred. There are negative numbers in the data set though

Comment: @djk11 . . . As the answer states, this is predicated on the values being positive and non-zero.